# Is numpy.argmax slower than MATLAB [~,idx] = max()?

Tags: python, performance, matlab, numpy, pandas

I am writing a Bayseian classifier for a normal distribution. I have both code in python and MATLAB which are nearly identical. However the MATLAB code runs about 50x faster than my Python script. I'm new to Python, so maybe there's something I did terribly wrong. I assume it's somewhere where I loop over the dataset.

Possibly numpy.argmax() is much slower than [~,idx]=max()? Looping through the data frame is slow? Bad use of dictionaries (previously I tried an object and it was even slow)?

Any advice is welcome.

**Python code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#import the data as a data frame
train_df = pd.read_table('hw1_traindata.txt',header = None)#training
train_df.columns = [1, 2] #rename column titles
```

The data here is a 2 columns (300 rows/samples for training and 300000 for test). This is the function parameters; mi and Si are the sample means and covariances.

```
case3_p = {'w': [], 'w0': [], 'W': []}
case3_p['w']={1:S1.I*m1,2:S2.I*m2,3:S3.I*m3}
case3_p['w0']={1: -1.0/2.0*(m1.T*S1.I*m1)-

1.0/2.0*np.log(np.linalg.det(S1)),
            2: -1.0/2.0*(m2.T*S2.I*m2)-1.0/2.0*np.log(np.linalg.det(S2)),
            3: -1.0/2.0*(m3.T*S3.I*m3)-1.0/2.0*np.log(np.linalg.det(S3))}
case3_p['W']={1: -1.0/2.0*S1.I,
           2: -1.0/2.0*S2.I,
           3: -1.0/2.0*S3.I}
#W1=-1.0/2.0*S1.I
#w1_3=S1.I*m1
#w01_3=-1.0/2.0*(m1.T*S1.I*m1)-1.0/2.0*np.log(np.linalg.det(S1))    
def g3(x,W,w,w0):
    return x.T*W*x+w.T*x+w0
```

This is the classifier/loop

```
train_df['case3'] = 0

for i in range(train_df.shape[0]):
    x = np.mat(train_df.loc[i,[1, 2]]).T#observation

    #case 3    
    vals = [g3(x,case3_p['W'][1],case3_p['w'][1],case3_p['w0'][1]),
            g3(x,case3_p['W'][2],case3_p['w'][2],case3_p['w0'][2]),
            g3(x,case3_p['W'][3],case3_p['w'][3],case3_p['w0'][3])]
    train_df.loc[i,'case3'] = np.argmax(vals) + 1 #add one to make it the class value
```

**Corresponding MATLAB code**

```
train = load('hw1_traindata.txt');
```

The discriminant functions

```
W1=-1/2*S1^-1;%there isn't one for the other cases
w1_3=S1^-1*m1';%fix the transpose thing
w10_3=-1/2*(m1*S1^-1*m1')-1/2*log(det(S1));
g1_3=@(x) x'*W1*x+w1_3'*x+w10_3';

W2=-1/2*S2^-1;
w2_3=S2^-1*m2';
w20_3=-1/2*(m2*S2^-1*m2')-1/2*log(det(S2));
g2_3=@(x) x'*W2*x+w2_3'*x+w20_3';

W3=-1/2*S3^-1;
w3_3=S3^-1*m3';
w30_3=-1/2*(m3*S3^-1*m3')-1/2*log(det(S3));
g3_3=@(x) x'*W3*x+w3_3'*x+w30_3';
```

The classifier

```
case3_class_tr = Inf(size(act_class_tr));
for i=1:length(train)
    x=train(i,:)';%current sample

    %case3
    vals = [g1_3(x),g2_3(x),g3_3(x)];%compute discriminant function value
    [~, case3_class_tr(i)] = max(vals);%get location of max

end
```

Answer (score 5):

In cases such as this it's best to profile your code. First I created some mock data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fname = 'hw1_traindata.txt'
ar = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
np.savetxt(fname, ar, delimiter='\t')

m1, m2, m3 = [np.mat(ar).T for ar in np.random.rand(3, 2)]
S1, S2, S3 = [np.mat(ar) for ar in np.random.rand(3, 2, 2)]
```

Then I wrapped your code in a function and profiled with the `lprun` (line_profiler) IPython magic. These are the results:

```
%lprun -f train train(fname, m1, S1, m2, S2, m3, S3)
Timer unit: 5.59946e-07 s

Total time: 4.77361 s
File: <ipython-input-164-563f57dadab3>
Function: train at line 1

Line #   Hits     Time  Per Hit  %Time  Line Contents
=====================================================
     1                                 def train(fname, m1, S1, m2, S2, m3, S3):
     2      1     9868   9868.0   0.1      train_df = pd.read_table(fname ,header = None)#training
     3      1      328    328.0   0.0      train_df.columns = [1, 2] #rename column titles
     4                                 
     5      1       17     17.0   0.0      case3_p = {'w': [], 'w0': [], 'W': []}
     6      1      877    877.0   0.0      case3_p['w']={1:S1.I*m1,2:S2.I*m2,3:S3.I*m3}
     7      1      356    356.0   0.0      case3_p['w0']={1: -1.0/2.0*(m1.T*S1.I*m1)-
     8                                 
     9      1      204    204.0   0.0      1.0/2.0*np.log(np.linalg.det(S1)),
    10      1      498    498.0   0.0                  2: -1.0/2.0*(m2.T*S2.I*m2)-1.0/2.0*np.log(np.linalg.det(S2)),
    11      1      502    502.0   0.0                  3: -1.0/2.0*(m3.T*S3.I*m3)-1.0/2.0*np.log(np.linalg.det(S3))}
    12      1      235    235.0   0.0      case3_p['W']={1: -1.0/2.0*S1.I,
    13      1      229    229.0   0.0                 2: -1.0/2.0*S2.I,
    14      1      230    230.0   0.0                 3: -1.0/2.0*S3.I}
    15                                 
    16      1     1818   1818.0   0.0      train_df['case3'] = 0
    17                                 
    18   1001    17409     17.4   0.2      for i in range(train_df.shape[0]):
    19   1000  4254511   4254.5  49.9          x = np.mat(train_df.loc[i,[1, 2]]).T#observation
    20                                 
    21                                         #case 3    
    22   1000   298245    298.2   3.5          vals = [g3(x,case3_p['W'][1],case3_p['w'][1],case3_p['w0'][1]),
    23   1000   269825    269.8   3.2                  g3(x,case3_p['W'][2],case3_p['w'][2],case3_p['w0'][2]),
    24   1000   274279    274.3   3.2                  g3(x,case3_p['W'][3],case3_p['w'][3],case3_p['w0'][3])]
    25   1000  3395654   3395.7  39.8          train_df.loc[i,'case3'] = np.argmax(vals) + 1
    26                                 
    27      1       45     45.0   0.0      return train_df
```

There are two lines that together take 90% of the time. So let's split these lines up a bit and rerun the profiler:

```
%lprun -f train train(fname, m1, S1, m2, S2, m3, S3)
Timer unit: 5.59946e-07 s

Total time: 6.15358 s
File: <ipython-input-197-92d9866b57dc>
Function: train at line 1

Line #   Hits      Time  Per Hit  %Time  Line Contents
======================================================
...     
    19   1000   5292988   5293.0   48.2          thing = train_df.loc[i,[1, 2]]  # Observation
    20   1000    265101    265.1    2.4          x = np.mat(thing).T
...     
    26   1000    143142    143.1    1.3          index = np.argmax(vals) + 1  # Add one to make it the class value
    27   1000   4164122   4164.1   37.9          train_df.loc[i,'case3'] = index
```

Most time is spent indexing the Pandas dataframe! Taking the `argmax` is only 1.5% of total execution time.

The situation can be improved somewhat by pre-allocating `train_df['case3']` and using `.iloc`:

```
%lprun -f train train(fname, m1, S1, m2, S2, m3, S3)
Timer unit: 5.59946e-07 s

Total time: 3.26716 s
File: <ipython-input-192-f6173cdf9990>
Function: train at line 1

Line #   Hits      Time  Per Hit  %Time  Line Contents
======= ======= ======================================
    16      1      1548   1548.0    0.0      train_df['case3'] = np.zeros(len(train_df))
...             
    19   1000   2608489   2608.5   44.7          thing = train_df.iloc[i,[0, 1]]  # Observation
    20   1000    228959    229.0    3.9          x = np.mat(thing).T
...             
    26   1000    123165    123.2    2.1          index = np.argmax(vals) + 1  # Add one to make it the class value
    27   1000   1849283   1849.3   31.7          train_df.iloc[i,2] = index
```

Still though, iterating individual values from Pandas dataframes in tight loops is a bad idea. In this case use Pandas only for loading the text-data (it's very good at it) but other than that use "raw" Numpy arrays. E.g. use `train_data = pd.read_table(fname, header=None).values`. And when you reach the analysis stage maybe go back to Pandas.

Some other ramblings:

- Use Python's zero-based indexing and don't go out of your way to use
  one-based indexing.
- Consider using normal Numpy arrays instead of matrices. When you use
  matrices you tend to mix them up with arrays and run into hard to debug
  problems.
- MATLAB has a JIT compliler, so a speed difference between Python and
  MATLAB is expected for loop heavy code.

Comment: Some other points: 1: It is easier and faster to loop over rows rather than indexes with python.  2: Using dicts every time through the loop is unnecessary and will also slow things down slightly.  3. You can use `lambda` or `partial` for the various `g3` functions.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Exactly what I was looking for.

TheBlackCat, can you elaborate one what you mean looping over rows rather than indexes?

Comment: Say you have a 2D numpy array `myarr`.  Rather than doing `for i in range(myarr.shape[0]):` and get the row with `row = myarr[i, :]`, you can just do `for row in myarr:`.  Or, if you also need the index, you can do `for i, row in enumerate(myarr):`.  Numpy uses views, so `row` is still part of `myarr`.  `row` takes no addition memory, and any changes to it also change the corresponding row in `myarr`.  You can do something similar with pandas a `DataFrame` using `df.iterrows()`, although this gives you the index and the row automatically: `for index, row in df.iterrows():`.

Answer (score -2):

It's really hard to tell, but straight out of the package Matlab will be faster than Numpy. Primarily because it comes with its own [Math Kernel Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library)

Whether 50x is a reasonable approximatino it'll be hard to compare basic Numpy vs Matlab's MKL.

There are other Python distribution that come with their own MKL such as [Enthought](https://www.enthought.com/) and [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/)

In Anaconda's [MKL Optimizations](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/mkl-optimizations/) page you'll see the chart comparing the difference between regular Anaconda and the one with MKL. The improvement is not linear, but definitely there.

Comment: `MKL` can help with some operations, but I don't think it will give any benefit for simple operations like finding the maximum of a vector.  In fact it doesn't look like it even has such a function.